# How to escape characters using INTO OUTFILE command in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I just want to ask how can I escape a character like (") and (,) in MySQL command?
Because I am trying to create a csv file. And I have a thousands of rows. Some rows consists of comma (,) and others consists of (") double qutoes. Now when I tried to export my table. I can't get the correct rows exactly as my query result.

Here's my sql code:

```
SELECT 
cscart_products.product_id,
cscart_product_descriptions.product,
cscart_product_descriptions.short_description,
cscart_product_descriptions.page_title,
cscart_products.list_price AS list_price,
cscart_product_prices.price AS selling_price
FROM cscart_products
LEFT JOIN cscart_product_prices
ON cscart_products.product_id = cscart_product_prices.product_id
LEFT JOIN cscart_product_descriptions
ON cscart_products.product_id = cscart_product_descriptions.product_id
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Users/ad00/Desktop/FIELDS/menu_fields.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I hope you can help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to do. You can find very good descibtion of the CSV file format and the solution to your problem in the following link:
[CSV specification](http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm)

Comment: page not found.